# Display txt contents below string then remove duplicate lines

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Need help creating a batch that displays a certain amount of text  (e.g 5 lines of text) from a txt file but only below a specific key word e.g 'Home' and finally removing any duplicate text

So ,

Search for specific string e.g 'Home' any text  below ‘home’  display not all just 5 lines worth and finally remove any duplicate sentence’s

I've tried modifying the following command .

```
@echo OFF

:: Get the number of lines in the file
set LINES=0
for /f "delims==" %%I in (data.txt) do (
set /a LINES=LINES+1
)

:: Print the last 10 lines (suggestion to use more courtsey of dmityugov)
set /a LINES=LINES-10
more +%LINES% < data.txt
```

[Displaying lines from text file in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744094/displaying-lines-from-text-file-in-a-batch-file)

[Read every 5th line using Batch Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471669/read-every-5th-line-using-batch-script?rq=1)

I don't know if its possible to remove duplicates

## Update

Yes that right *duplicate lines within the block of 5 following the keyword*

However Don't worry about removing duplicates my main concern is just trying to show text below a certain string e.g Home

I have the below command but doesn't show all information below the text just one line ideally I would like to adjust the amount displayed e.g 5 lines worth of data

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Assemble the list of line numbers
set numbers=
set "folder=C:\test\world.txt"
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /N /C:"home" "%folder%"') do (
set /A before=%%a-0, after=%%a+3
set "numbers=!numbers!!before!: !after!: "
)
rem Search for the lines
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%folder%" ^| findstr /B  "%numbers%"') do echo. %%b)
```

[batch script to print previous and next lines of search string in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940198/batch-script-to-print-previous-and-next-lines-of-search-string-in-a-text-file)

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicates?" Are these duplicate lines within the block of 5 following the keyword, or any line of those 5 that has a duplicate anywhere else in the file, or has a duplicate within the block(s) alreay shown? Do you want to show 5 lines (except duplicated text) or what's left of the 5 lines after the duplicated text is removed? Do you want to display the line containing the target string? Is the line containing the target counted as line 1 of the 5? Editing-in an exaple would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Magoo I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: remove variables starting $
For %%b IN ($) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
SET /a before=0
SET /a after=5
SET "target=home"
SET /a count=0
SET "file=q24813694.txt"
FOR /f "delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /i /n /L /c:"%target%" "%file%"'
 ) DO SET /a $!count!=%%a-%before%&SET /a count+=1
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r "." "%file%"') DO (
 SET "printed="
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims==" %%m IN ('set $ 2^>nul') DO IF NOT DEFINED printed IF %%a geq %%n (
  SET /a count=%%n+%before%+%after%
  IF %%a geq !count! (SET "%%m=") ELSE (SET "printed=Y"&ECHO %%b)
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This routine should do the trick. You'd need to set `file` to suit yourself, of course; and to set the `target`.

If you want to set the number of lines before to print, and those after (which includes the target line) then those should work, too.